# What is a term for an attitude/life that eschews luxury or comfort?

Tags: words, terminology

A while back I had read an article (in English) online about an Japanese ceramics artist and his work, with the writer describing the artist's rather spartan furnishings as a result of his attitude or lifestyle that eschewed luxury or comfort, allowing him to better focus on his art.  Whether that was actually true or not, he described it using a Japanese word, perhaps a zen concept, explaining and using that idea to paint an ethereal picture of the artist's dedication to his work. I don't know how much liberty he was taking (if any at all) with the word he was using, but here I am asking if there's anyone out there familiar with a Japanese word that encapsulates this idea/concept.

**Added:**
I had been scanning thru hundreds of images of Japanese ceramics and checking into artists' background and then became fixated on some fantastic examples of [金継]{きんつぎ} / [金繕い]{きんつくろい} and this is where I lost where I was before when I can across that term I'm inquiring about. I don't think I can make my way back (though I've tried) to that particular article.

In all honesty, I don't think I'd be able to give a yea/nay on the correct one any more, even if saw it, but I appreciate all of the suggestions that have been offered.  I think, so far, that [[質素倹約]{しっそけんやく}](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B3%AA%E7%B4%A0%E5%80%B9%E7%B4%84) probably best approximates what it was that I was looking for even though the definition doesn't come close to how romantically the author of the piece described it.

Comment: Was it wabi-sabi?

Comment: Do you remember the name of the artist, or where you saw the article? The most mundane word for this concept is [質素](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B3%AA%E7%B4%A0), but probably he was using an uncommon term that sounds cooler... :-)

Comment: @Ben Roffey No, definitely wasn't wabi-sabi.

Comment: I was going to suggest 質素｛しっそ｝, シンプル or 贅沢{ぜいたく｝なし.

Comment: 粗衣粗食｛そいそしょく｝ですか？

Comment: なんだろう・・「[素朴]{そぼく}」「[簡素]{かんそ}」もありそうな気が・・って連想ゲームかクイズみたいになってるしぃ。。

Comment: @naruto Your 質素 link led me to [質素倹約](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B3%AA%E7%B4%A0%E5%80%B9%E7%B4%84) – thank you.